# MySQL - get the sum of the column value(s) based on same filed on the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a mysql table called **tbl_collection** and another table that has the name of the customers. I made an inner join. Join works well.

This is my *tbl_collection* table

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| customer  |    date    |    ach_val    | 
+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     30002 | 2012-02-02 | 200           |
|     30002 | 2012-02-05 | 250           | 
|     30002 | 2012-02-06 | 122           |
|     30003 | 2012-02-03 | 500           |
|     30004 | 2012-02-04 | 425           |
|     30004 | 2012-02-06 | 225           |
|     30004 | 2012-02-10 | 300           |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

What I want is to get the sum of each customers ach_val for each month.

For example sum of ach_val of each customer, in 2012-02.

(ach_val) of 30002 = 200 + 250 + 122 = 572

(ach_val) of 30003 = 500             = 500

(ach_val) of 30004 = 425 + 225 + 300 = 950

This is what i was trying to do.

```
$r = mysql_query("select tbl_collection.customer, sum(tbl_collection.col_ach) as coll from tbl_collection inner join tbl_mas_customer on tbl_mas_customer.customer = tbl_collection.customer where rep = '503' and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2012-02'");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select customer,sum(ach_val) from tbl_collection group by customer,month(date);
```